# Does Charge the Magi grant you a standard attack as well?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

My Pathfinder Magus just took [Charge of the Magi](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/rite-publishing---magus-arcana/charge-of-the-magi-su) which looks like a fun time.

It says (emphasis mine):

> The magus can spend 1 point from her arcane pool **as a swift action when charging,** so she can turn herself into a living projectile that blasts her opponent with a jolt of arcane power. **She makes a charge as normal.** If her attack hits, she deals an **extra** 1d6 points of force damage plus an additional 1d6 for every 3 magus levels she possesses in addition to her attack’s normal damage, and her foe must make a Fortitude save (DC 10 + half her magus class level + her Intelligence modifier) or be knocked prone. This extra damage is doubled on a critical hit, in addition upon a critical hit a +2 circumstance bonus is added to the DC of the save. When making this charge, she is considered to be flying. She can move over pits and other hazards, but she lands in the space where her charge ends and suffers any drawbacks for standing there after resolving her attack. If she misses the ability is expended.

So normally when I charge, I get a normal attack when I get there. Do I still get that attack or is me hitting the target as a living projectile the only I attack I get that turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still get the usual attack, with extra nd6 damage from the feat. The text you quoted cleearly says "in addition to her attack's normal damage".